# User's last time interaction with a web page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, timestamp

I want to save the timestamp when the last time a customer interacted with a web page - clicked the mouse, tapped the keyboard or moved the mouse.

I will use the above timestamp to compute the remaining time until the Web Token expires.

Comment: The only way to do this is to make listeners for any interaction, and send an AJAX to the server telling it a user interacted. The server can then adjust the web token accordingly.

Comment: @Amadan: Though keep in mind that sending an AJAX request to the server every time the mouse move event fires is probably not smart. Perhaps include a check to ensure it only sends every 30 seconds (or whatever duration suits)

Comment: Maybe you could add event listeners on the document object on "mousemove" and "keypress" in the service the service handling security in your app. However, this is not a bullet proof solution. Indeed, if you use external libraries that could stop event bubbling, you might not get all the events.

Comment: @Amadan,in addition to the token validation at server side, I'm also using the client side calculation to make sure the user not browsing the pages while the token is expired.

Comment: @musefan Yeah, some delay would be smart. Still, sending this to the server is the only way, since the client might be thinking "oo, look at all the interaction the user is doing"; while the server ticks down and expires the token.

Answer (score 1):

You could use RxJS like in this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/4kPM5FX6vX2QGC0xDQQO

The core function is `_listenToEvent`:

```
function _listenToEvent(name, debounceTime) {
  rxjs.fromEvent(document, name)
  .pipe(
    rxjs.operators.debounceTime(debounceTime)
  )
  .subscribe(() => _updateTimestamp())
}
```

Basically, with this function, you can listen to even on the document object. The `debounceTime` argument allows you to debounce event to be sure not that send an AJAX request as soon as the mouse moves but rather when it stops moving, same for the `keypress`. Debouncing on the `click` event is not necessary as the user won't normally click 300 times a seconds.

You could normally easily integrate this with a `user` service that would send the AJAX request when you need to. Note that this might not be a bullet proof solution. I think that if some of your code stop event bubbling, RxJS could miss them.